# How to password protect a google sheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have a Google Sheet with data that is protected - the user can't edit the sheet. When the AskUser function is ran, a pop-up box appears that asks the user if they wish to "unprotect" the sheet. When they click "No", they will be told nothing will happen. When they click "Yes", they will be told they need to submit a password. I have three problems:

1. I don't know how to set a password.
2. I don't know how bring up a dialogue box where the user can submit a password.
3. I don't know how to make it check if it's the correct password.

I've tried downloading pre-password protected sheets and checking the code, but they use a weird HTML format. Here's what I have so far:

```
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() 
      .createMenu('Custom Menu')
      .addItem('Show alert', 'showAlert')
      .addToUi();
}

function AskUser() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi(); 

  var result = ui.alert(
     'Worksheet Protected!',
     'Do you want to unprotect the worksheet?',
      ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);


  if (result == ui.Button.YES) {
    //This is where I want the password dialogue box prompt
    ui.alert('The worksheet will be unprotected after you submit the right password.');
  } else {

    ui.alert('The worksheet will not be unprotected.');
  }
}
```

I'm completely new to Javascript and Google Sheets.

Comment: Take a look at PropertiesService for storing information, like a set password. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Setting a password**

Use `PropertiesService` to store a password

```
function setPassword(password) {
  let prop = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();
  prop.setProperty("sheetpassword", password);
}
```

**Bringing up password form**

Create an html form in a file, eg. `passwordform`.

Then when you want to show the form, call `createHtmlOutputFromFile`

```
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
spreadsheet.show(HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('passwordform'));
```

On form submit, call the check password function

`onclick='google.script.run.checkPassword(document.getElementById("passwordInput"));'`

**Checking password**

Get the property from `PropertiesService` and see if it equals

```
function checkPassword(password) {
  let prop = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();
  if (prop.getProperty("sheetpassword") === null || prop.getProperty("sheetpassword") !== password) {
    return false; // Doesn't match DB
  } 
}
```

Comment: if they can run the script, can't they open the code and see the password?

Comment: not if you dont store it in the script. For example you could add a menu to set the password as a user, then don't add that menu if theres a password found in PropertiesService

Comment: interesting! although a savvy user could write their own script to read that propertiesservice anyway,I don't think this is a savvy user situation

Comment: Haha yes saving a password in plaintext with an exposed api is definitely not secure :)

Answer (score 0):

It is a trick but it's useful to free account user!
Use `onOpen()` function and little code below.

```
var inputPassword;
function checkPassword(){  
  
  var refAddress = 'https://script.google.com/d/' + ScriptApp.getScriptId() + '/edit';
  var curAddress = refAddress;
  Logger.log(curAddress);  
  
  var referPassword = 1234;

  if( refAddress == curAddress){
      while(referPassword != inputPassword){
      inputPassword = Browser.inputBox('[Password Check]', '[Input Password!]', Browser.Buttons.OK_CANCEL);
    }
  }
}
```

Refer to [my blog](https://blog.naver.com/dsayhong/222221373617) for more information.